# Selecting threshold for generalized Pareto distribution in R

Tags: r, pareto-distribution

I'm using the `POT` Package in R for fitting a Generalized Pareto distribution to my data. For choosing an approximate threshold I'm using the `tcplot()` and `mrlplot()` the following way(`x` is the data containing vector)

```
tcplot(x,u.range=c(0,quantile(x,probs=0.995)))
mrlplot(x,u.range=c(0,quantile(x,probs=0.995)),col=c("green","black","green"),nt=200 )
```

But I get a bit confused sometimes as what value I'll choose as threshold. Particularly as mentioned in [this site](http://www.bioss.ac.uk/people/adam/teaching/OR_EVT/2007/node23.html) that

> interpretation of these plots often requires a good deal of
>   subjective judgement

For example what would be the threshold given the following plot? 
[image: A parameter stability and MRL plot]

Answer (score 1):

I believe the threshold is selected as the point at which the MRL plot becomes kind of linear, which to my eye is 2.75 on the MRL plot.